# Conjunction usage

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Is the following phrase grammatically correct? I looked it up in.. well, somewhere... to find out if there is any specific meaning behind the use of AND repeatedly in the same sentence. so far, I found none. The sentence  below appears in quite technical literature, but doesnt seem very technical (I would say doesnt look like solid English). It is probably a translation. Am I right?

Support national institutions in the testing AND introduction AND promotion of vegetable varieties.

Comment: It would be more common to use a comma instead of the first *and*, but more than one *and* isn't wrong - why would it be? (I'm assuming the use of all caps for that word was done by you to highlight the word?)

Comment: It suggests that the elements break down a little differently - *testing, introduction and promotion...* suggests a single process with three aspects to it. On the other hand, in *testing and introduction and promotion*, *testing* is one thing and *introduction and promotion* is another.

Comment: Repetition could be for emphasis. But it's always useful to have context. I'm guessing this is a list of requirements for a job (or possibly a tender for work), in which case they want to make clear that all three are separate requirements, rather than just having skills/experience in one part of the process.

Comment: all explanations make perfect sense. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more you use one word in a sentence, the more clunky it seem.

(e.g. One day I went to the park with **him**. I told **him** to sit down. I also asked **him** if he wanted a snack.)

Two or more conjunctions to  close together do the same.

> Support national institutions in the testing and introduction and in the promotion of vegetable varieties.

To compress the sentence, do this:

> Support national institutions in the testing, introduction, and in the promotion of vegetable varieties.

To use parallel form, write like this:

> Support national institutions in the testing, introduction, and promoting of vegetable varieties.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I'd say that an 'and' is redundant in the sentence (the last one). But, with the addition of some words, one can set it right.

> Support national institutions in the testing and introduction, and in the promotion of vegetable varieties.

Normally, I'd take out the first *and* in the sentence and replace it with a comma, but since they do not appear to be in a sequence, I felt it better to isolate the last part of the sentence.

Comment: very useful hint indeed. thank you!